# Returning button text with the onAction property

Tags: java, javafx

I have a method that takes in a list of names and then create buttons for each name on the list. I want to return the name in  the form of a string or which number in the list was clicked, but I find it hard to do

```
public static String display(List<String> names) {
    Stage window = new Stage();
    window.setTitle("title");
    GridPane layout = new GridPane();

    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        Button b = new Button(names.get(i);
        GridPane.setConstraints(b, 0, i);
        b.setOnAction(e - > {
            // return names.get(i);
            // or the number in the list
            // or the text of the button
        });

        layout.getChildren().add(b);
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.showAndWait();

    return null;
}
```

What I tried:

```
    String s = "";
    b.setOnAction(e - > {
        s = b.getText();
    });
    
    return s;
```

But I get the following error: `local variable is defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effective final`.

Comment: Your Button already has the necessary information as set in `new Button(names.get(i)...`, so just return the Button `label`

Comment: I guessed as much, but how do i do that?

Comment: `return b.getLabel());` ?  Read the javadocs

Comment: try `b.getText()`.

Comment: getLabel is undefined for the type Button.

Comment: `Button b = new Button(names.get(i); GridPane.setConstraints(b, 0, i);` looks fishy to me.

Comment: b.getText() gives the error void methods cannot return a value

Comment: There is no value to return in a `Button` `ActionHandler`. Just print it or assign it to a `Label` or something.

Comment: its a list of options. I need to know which option is clicked so I can handel it in the main program.

Comment: Sounds like a bad design to me. Anyway, I updated the answer.

Comment: A hack workaround for the "must be final": `String[] s = new String[1]{""};`. Then you can set and read the value inside the array. That works around the final restriction since the array itself is never reassigned, only the value inside of it. Clunky, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do

```
public static String display(List<String> names) {

  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

  Stage window = new Stage();
  window.setTitle("title");
  GridPane layout = new GridPane();

  for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    String name = names.get(i);
    Button b = new Button(name); GridPane.setConstraints(b, 0, i);
    b.setOnAction(e -> {
        result.append(name);
        window.close();
    });
    layout.getChildren().add(b);
  }

  Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
  window.setScene(scene);
  window.showAndWait();

  return result.toString();

}
```

If you use a `VBox`, which seems more natural, you can make the code cleaner (since you don't need the list index):

```
public static String display(List<String> names) {

  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

  Stage window = new Stage();
  window.setTitle("title");
  VBox layout = new VBox();

  for (String name : names) {
    Button b = new Button(name); 
    b.setOnAction(e -> {
        result.append(name);
        window.close();
    });
    layout.getChildren().add(b);
  }
  Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
  window.setScene(scene);
  window.showAndWait();

  return result.toString();    
}
```

Comment: Idk who you are James, but if I ever meet you I will buy you a chicken nugget :)

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options here.

**Option 1:**

```
System.out.println(b.getText());
```

**Option 2: What I prefer**

```
Button tempButton = ((Button)e.getSource());
System.out.println(tempButton.getText());
```

**Full Code: I would recommend against doing this! I think you should use either `Alert` or `Dialog` to accomplish this!**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList();
        names.add("john");
        names.add("Kim");
        
        Button button = new Button("List of Names Menu");
        button.setOnAction((e) -> {
            System.out.println(display(names));
        });

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    public String display(List <String> names) {
        Label label = new Label();

        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.setTitle("title");
        GridPane layout = new GridPane();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            Button b = new Button(names.get(i));
            GridPane.setConstraints(b, 0, i);
            b.setOnAction((e) -> {
                label.setText(b.getText());
                window.close();
            });
            layout.getChildren().add(b);
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.showAndWait();

        return label.getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked if i wanted to print the label, but I want to return it.

Comment: If you see the edit I did on my question that is excactly what i tried to do.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create an `Alert` or a `Dialog`. I would use a builtin `Alert` or `Dialog` to do this.

Comment: name is a list of users. The idea is that the user click the name they want and I return the name to the main program and continue the program for that spesific user.

Comment: That's pretty much irrelevant to the question. Especially, given the code you posted. The idea is the same either way. I don't know why I didn't think of `StringBuilder` as James suggested.